# detailed listing and description of freearc switches

Tags: compression, archiving, command-line-arguments, documentation

The documentation that comes with freearc seems a little bit sparse and outdated unfortunately, at least when reading posts on http://encode.ru/

And following the trial and error principle is quite unsatisfying (one has to discover e.g. that extracting files from created archives does not lead to bit identical copies of the original quite some times - depending on selected methods and switches.

Is there any publicly available document that lists all command-line switches and their meaning in detail for the freearc archiver (and which would be comparable to the file "rar.txt" in the winrar-package)?

Comment: What's wrong with [The documentation on FreeArc 0.40](http://freearc.org/FreeArc040-eng.htm)?

Comment: e.g. it lacks description of parameters for "4x4" and "tor"  methods that get mentioned in quite some encode.ru posts

Comment: Try looking at the source code.

Comment: FreeArc says the best way to get help with its software is by contacting its [project administrators](http://sourceforge.net/p/freearc/_members/), two of which are developers

Comment: tried looking at the code, but I'm neither a haskell programmer, nor do I speak russian, which would be necessary to understand the comments